# No python detected by vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter

My vscode shows version `3.9.13 64bit` of python:

[image]

However there are many versions of python installed on my machine (dont know how!)

[image]

When I run python shell in terminal, it picks up version `3.7.9`

[image]

When I open jupyter notebook, and run any cell it says

Also when I run a cell in the jupyter notebook, it detects no python installed:

[image]

Also it does not seem to detect any kernels installed:

[image]

What is happening here?!! Is my Ubuntu  installation screwed up?

I want same python (preferably 3.9, but 3.7 will also be ok) at all places: vscode bottom bar, terminal and also jupyter notebook. Also `pip` should correspond to the same python. That is installing package through `pip install` from terminal should make the package available to both python file and jupyter notebook. This is how it works on my Windows machine.

Comment: The one you get in the terminal is whichever one is found first when searching the system `PATH`. https://superuser.com/q/238987/1749748

Comment: What do you see in the output logs? (`View > Output`). Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19680, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10552, and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16684

Comment: Output tab is completely empty.

Comment: Can you open jupyter outside of vscode? Maybe you can install anaconda to manage your python environment and use jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-install jupyter's extensions and restart vs code, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have several Python(s) installed in your system. The typical installation path would be in `/usr/bin/python3`.
Commonly, `/usr/bin/python3` it's a symbolic link pointing toward the Python version installed in your system.

```bash
$ ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 Mar 13  2020 python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     5486352 Jul 28  2020 python3.8
```

When you type `python3` in your terminal, the one that you get is **the first** found when searching the system `PATH`. You can easily check printing `PATH` variable

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The same reasoning is valid for `pip`. I suggest you remove Python versions that you don't use.

Regarding VS Code, you can select the Python environment used using the bar at the bottom. To check whether VS Code is really using that environment, you can try to "right-click" a Python file and then `Run Python file in a terminal`.

That command should output what is happening in the terminal tab.

If you are scared about removing other Python versions, you may create a separated Python environment. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) you can find some info about Python environments and use to use them with VS Code

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks why their jupyter extension reports that they don't have python installed (and implicitly- probably- what they can do to remedy this). What you've said should just be a comment. I've already commented about the `PATH` search.